# switch case giving strange response within onActivityResult in android

Tags: java, android, android-activity, switch-statement, break

I have Activity within which i am opening intents for camera ,voice and video .i am using onActivityResult  for it . But when onActivityResult is getting called i am observing something very strange all the case within switch case are getting called means its gng in all the cases .

How it is possible .Am i dpong something wrong?  .

Below is my code

```
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
     {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); 

       if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){




          switch(requestCode) { 

             case 1:

                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                System.out.println("selectedimage"+selectedImage);
                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,       filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();


                yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
                /* Now you have choosen image in Bitmap format in object "yourSelectedImage". You can use it in
                 *  way you want! */



                btn_img.setImageBitmap(yourSelectedImage);





        case 0:
            try {
                yourSelectedImage = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                btn_img.setImageBitmap(yourSelectedImage);
                System.out.println("try for 0"+yourSelectedImage);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }

        case 2:
            try {


                    System.out.println("ooookkkkkk");


                        System.out.println("SELECT_AUDIO");
                        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                        selectedPath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                        try {
                            System.out.println("try for 2"+yourSelectedImage);
                             btn_img.setImageBitmap(yourSelectedImage);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            System.out.println("catch"+yourSelectedImage);
                            // TODO: handle exception
                        }
                        System.out.println("SELECT_AUDIO Path : " + selectedPath);
                       // doFileUpload();





            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }

        case 3:
            try {




                        System.out.println("SELECT_AUDIO");
                        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                        selectedPath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                        try {
                            System.out.println("try for 3"+yourSelectedImage);
                             btn_img.setImageBitmap(yourSelectedImage);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            System.out.println("catch"+yourSelectedImage);
                            // TODO: handle exception
                        }
                        System.out.println("SELECT_AUDIO Path : " + selectedPath);
                       // doFileUpload();




            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }

        }


    }






}
```

Comment: break before next case

Comment: thanxxx brother ..how can i forget that

Comment: where did you break the cases?

Comment: Rahul you are forgetting the basic programming. Please add break statement in each case.

Comment: i think rahul forgot to mention break; in every switch case.. Sometimes it happens

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add `break;` at the end of every cases and check

```
switch(requestCode) { 
   case 1:
    //code
    break;
   case 2:
    //code
   break;
   .
   .
   default:

   break;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a 'break' statement after each case.

ex:

```
  switch(value)
    {
    case 1:
    //code..
    break;

    case 2:
    //code
    break;
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your answer while I was answering. Your answer hadn't shown up yet.